# Clean up tools' tags: [name] & [platform-name]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

There are numerous tools for different platforms which have distinguishable proper names (logcat, uiautomator, adb and etc.) and exist only on that one platform.

Do we really need to have both tags:

"name" and "platform-name"?

e.g.:

[uiautomator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiautomator) and [android-uiautomator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-uiautomator)

[logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logcat) and [android-logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-logcat)

(these are most obvious for me but there should be more and not only for [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag)

Tags like [monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monkey) and [android-monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-monkey) probably should be handled differently because proper name `monkey` is (at least for me) less distinguishable than `logcat`